# Speeding up Datatables load time on client side

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am using datatablejs on client side for displaying the database to client. I download the database from server initially using backbone indexeddb adapter and store it in indexedDB so as to support offline access to data. However, datatables take approx around 5 minutes to render 20,000 entries. This is my JS code:

```
render_data: function(entity_collection) {
        //create table body in memory
        tbody = $('<tbody>');
        tbody.html('');

        //iterate over the collection, fill row template with each object 
        //and append the row to table
        entity_collection.each(function(model) {
            tbody.append(this.row_template(model.toJSON()));
        }, this);
        //put table body in DOM
        this.$('#list_table')
            .append(tbody);
        //initialize datatable lib on the table    
        this.$('#list_table')
            .dataTable();
        $("#loaderimg")
            .hide();
        $("#sort-helptext").show();
},
```

Table headers:

```
<script type="text/template" id="person_table_template"> 
    <tr> 
        <th>Id</th> 
        <th>Name</th> 
        <th>Father Name</th> 
        <th>Village</th> 
        <th>Group</th> 
        <th></th> 
    </tr> 
</script>
```

JSON which is converted to html:

```
Object {
    age: 45, 
    father_name: "Jiyan Sah ", 
    gender: "F", 
    group: Object, 
    id: 10000000155392, 
    label: "Gangajali Devi (Sahila Rampur,Jiyan Sah )", 
    online_id: 10000000155392, 
    person_name: "Gangajali Devi ", 
    phone_no: "", 
    resource_uri: "/coco/api/v1/person/10000000155392/", 
    village: Object
}
```

Can anybody suggest about how to increase the performance of datatable?

Comment: Can you provide sample data row and template ?

Comment: @DamianKrawczyk Table headers:
<script type="text/template" id="person_table_template">
       <tr>
       <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Father Name</th>
       <th>Village</th>
       <th>Group</th>
       <th></th>
    </tr>
</script>

Comment: JSON which is converted to html:
Object {age: 45, father_name: "Jiyan Sah ", gender: "F", group: Object, id: 10000000155392, label: "Gangajali Devi (Sahila Rampur,Jiyan Sah )", online_id: 10000000155392, person_name: "Gangajali Devi ", phone_no: "", resource_uri: "/coco/api/v1/person/10000000155392/", videos_seen: Array[19], village: Object}

Comment: my 2cents, why should we not assume that the delay is partly on the browser too, to draw the table onto the page. put a table-layout:fixed  style to it and see if that helps. more info here http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#propdef-table-layout

Answer (score 9):

Firstly, the is no need to append data on each iteration, you can do it once after loop.

```
var tmp_str = '';

entity_collection.each(function(model) {
    tmp_str+=this.row_template(model.toJSON())
}, this);

tbody.append(tmp_str);
```

But to really speed-up the app i recommend you to change render way - now you render all data at once and have no information what part of information is watched but client. Lazy loading can help you - for eg. you render first 100 items, when page is scrolled to the bottom on the list you render + 100 and so on.

If you need some code help let me know.

Comment: I agree that lazy loading is a solution, but the only problem is that my data is in indexed db, so I don't need to send ajax call. And DOM isn't helping.

Comment: so you can once build a collection from indexeddb and the render slices, or get necessary slice with limited query

Comment: How can we build collection from indexeddb?

Comment: @Gaurav check this stuff - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/ - its about how to operate with indexeddb. On Backbone side follow this logic - create instance of BB collection, pass it to view and subscribe this view on collection reset event. Finally, when you got data from indexeddb query and proceed it to proper structure (in need) pass this data to BB collection with .reset method.

Comment: Did you test this out? Appending all at once as you say at least is slower than appending each one try it out. the reason is CSS which slows down

Comment: @ThorstenArtner'Austria' , i think you are wrong. Checkout this test - http://jsperf.com/once-vs-multiappend

Comment: okay i'm not talking about Jquery methods i was talking about DOM Methods createElement cloneNode and appendChild. Sorry, i dont use JQuery, so i think for JQuery you are right

Answer (score 2):

Try to build the datatable directly from your js object (see [DataTables Example here](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html)) instead of building a DOM object first.

Maybe datatablejs is faster in evaluating json arrays than in analysing such big DOM objects (and deleting most of it again)

Going this way you can set `"bDeferRender": true` which will cause that datatablejs will only render visible rows giving you a huge speed boost (see [the datatablejs features page](https://datatables.net/usage/features))

By using the js array initialization you lose HTML fallback for users without JavaScript of course - but I guess that's not your audience ;-)

Also take a look at [disabling CSS height matching](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedColumns/css_size.html)
This could save you some rendering time.

Comment: "Maybe datatablejs is faster in evaluating json arrays than in analysing such big DOM objects" I'll try this but again, I am also not sure if it will work.

Answer (score 0):

if you want speed improvement, write your own function with Javascript and not use Jquery.

!!!!    Its faster to first append and then add.   !!!!!

use also cloneNode which is faster then document.createElement only create once and clone.
Look at this and place in the html <body onload="alert (new Date().getTime()-b);">

it tooks 700 ms to generate a datatable with 20000 entries of course it depends on the machine  and data reading

```
 var a=new Date().getTime ();
 var table_master=document.createElement ("table");
 var tbody_master=document.createElement ("tbody");
 var tr_master=document.createElement ("tr");
 var td_master=document.createElement ("td");
 var i,u, tr, td;
 document.body.appendChild (table_master);
 table_master.appendChild (tbody_master);

 for (i=0;i<4000;i++)
        {
        tr=tr_master.cloneNode ();
        tbody_master.appendChild(tr);   // check what happens if you put this line after for operation , when you first add the cells with data to tr and then append to the tbody, that would slow down imense
        for (u=0;u<5;u++)
            {
            td=td_master.cloneNode();
            tr.appendChild (td);
            td.appendChild (document.createTextNode("hello"));
            }
        }
```

Comment: This will surely help. But datatables provide a search and sort functionality. We won't get that if we use this solution.

Comment: But at least you can put up your dom as i told you , try it, first append and then add, you are doing the opponent.....  you put the cells to the row the row to the tbody , the tbody to the table and then the tbody to the DOM, try in the other way first append table to Dom then append tbody to table then append the row and then append the cells and then append the data

Comment: this.$('#list_table').dataTable(); Statement is taking 99% of the loading time. This statement is the problem for me. Appending to DOM is taking negligible time in my case.

Answer (score -4):

Hey Brother Check this out this may help u -------

Client Side code -----

```
$("#table-tripNote").dataTable({
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sZeroRecords": "No records to display",
                    "sSearch": "Search from all Records"
                },
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "bDestroy": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "frmTrip.aspx/GetMemberNotesByTrip",
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "bDeferRender": true,
                "aoColumns":
                            [
                                null,
                                null,
                                null,
                                null,
                                null,
                                null,
                                null
                            ],
                "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                    $.ajax({
                        "dataType": 'json',
                        "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        "type": "GET",
                        "url": sSource,
                        "data": aoData,
                        "success":
                                                    function (msg) {

                                                        var json = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d);
                                                        fnCallback(json);
                                                        $("#table-tripNote").show();
                                                    }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Server side code---

```
[WebMethod()]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string GetMemberNotesByTrip(string sEcho, int iDisplayStart, int iDisplayLength)
{

    string rawSearch = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["sSearch"].Trim();

    var whereClause = string.Empty;

    var filteredWhere = "1=1";

    var wrappedSearch = rawSearch.Trim();
    var Tempsb = new StringBuilder();

    Tempsb.Append("mbrid=" + MemberID);
    if (TripID != 0)
    {
        Tempsb.Append("and trpid=" + TripID);
    }
    else
        Tempsb.Append("and trpid=0");

    if (rawSearch.Length > 0)
    {
        Tempsb.Append("AND ( ISNULL(trpDate,'''') LIKE ");
        Tempsb.Append("'%" + wrappedSearch + "%'");
        Tempsb.Append(" OR clrFullName LIKE ");
        Tempsb.Append("'%" + wrappedSearch + "%'");
        Tempsb.Append(" OR clrPhone LIKE ");
        Tempsb.Append("'%" + wrappedSearch + "%'");
        Tempsb.Append(" OR clrRelationshipToMember LIKE ");
        Tempsb.Append("'%" + wrappedSearch + "%'");
        Tempsb.Append(" OR trpNote LIKE ");
        Tempsb.Append("'%" + wrappedSearch + "%'");
        Tempsb.Append(" OR clrOrganization LIKE ");
        Tempsb.Append("'%" + wrappedSearch + "%'");
        Tempsb.Append(" OR trpIsGrievance LIKE ");
        Tempsb.Append("'%" + wrappedSearch + "%'");
        Tempsb.Append(")");
    }

    if (Tempsb.Length > 0)
        filteredWhere = Tempsb.ToString();

    string orderByClause = string.Empty;
    orderByClause = "trpDate desc";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["iSortCol_0"]));

    sb.Append(" ");

    sb.Append(HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["sSortDir_0"]);

    orderByClause = sb.ToString();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(orderByClause))
    {
        orderByClause = orderByClause.Replace("0", ", trpDate ");
        orderByClause = orderByClause.Replace("1", ", clrFullName ");
        orderByClause = orderByClause.Replace("2", ", clrPhone ");
        orderByClause = orderByClause.Replace("3", ", clrRelationshipToMember ");
        orderByClause = orderByClause.Replace("4", ", clrOrganization ");
        orderByClause = orderByClause.Replace("5", ", trpIsGrievance ");
        orderByClause = orderByClause.Replace("6", ", trpNote ");

        orderByClause = orderByClause.Remove(0, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        orderByClause = "pronID ASC";
    }

    DataSet ds = clsTrip.GetTripNotesMaster(filteredWhere, orderByClause, iDisplayLength, iDisplayStart, true);


    List<clsTrip> lstTripNotesGrv = new List<clsTrip>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        clsTrip lsttripNotes = new clsTrip();
        lsttripNotes.clrFullName = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["clrFullName"].ToString();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["trpDate"].ToString()))
            lsttripNotes.trpDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["trpDate"].ToString());
        else
            lsttripNotes.trpDate = DateTime.MinValue;

        lsttripNotes.clrPhone = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["clrPhone"].ToString();
        lsttripNotes.clrRelationshipToMember = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["clrRelationshipToMember"].ToString();
        lsttripNotes.clrOrganization = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["clrOrganization"].ToString();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["trpIsGrievance"].ToString()))
            lsttripNotes.trpIsGrievance = Convert.ToBoolean(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["trpIsGrievance"].ToString());
        else
            lsttripNotes.trpIsGrievance = false;
        lsttripNotes.trpNote = (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["trpNote"].ToString());

        lstTripNotesGrv.Add(lsttripNotes);
    }
    int TotalRec = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[1].Rows[0][0]);

    var result = from c in lstTripNotesGrv
                 select new[] { 
                       //Convert.ToString(c.pronID),                               
                       c.trpDate !=null && c.trpDate!=DateTime.MinValue ? string.Format("{0:MMM d, yyyy}",c.trpDate):"-",
                       c.clrFullName.ToString(),
                       c.clrPhone.ToString(),
                       c.clrRelationshipToMember.ToString(),
                       c.clrOrganization.ToString(),
                       ( Convert.ToBoolean(c.trpIsGrievance)?"Yes":"No"),
                       c.trpNote
                   };

    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return jss.Serialize(new
    {
        sEcho,
        iTotalRecords = TotalRec,
        iTotalDisplayRecords = TotalRec,
        aaData = result
    });
}
```

Comment: How does it help when the data is to be retrieved from indexedDB? All of my data is kept in IndexedDB.